# NginX - Rewrite http_referer

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx as a proxy to my backend server. And my application will store all the referer url to database. In order to reduce the space of the database, I want to ignore some of the referer by some condition.

I want to remove some of the http_referer if the uri contain some string.

Since nginx cannot use [proxy_set_header Referer ""] inside "if{...}" ,

So, I try to use "map" , but it still doesn't work.
Here is my configuration

```
http {
....
  map $http_referer $ref {
     default $http_referer;
  }
....
}

server {
......
  if ($request_uri ~ .*XXXXXXX.*) {
     set $ref "";     
  }
  proxy_set_header Referer $ref;
...... 
}
```

- I can create a variable $ref
- It can map $ref to the header by using "proxy_set_header Referer $ref"
- But the "if" cannot change the value of $ref

Is that we cannot change the global variable inside "if"?

Comment: I would implement the filtering inside your application which saves the information to the database. This way you don't create unnecessary dependencies between your web server software configuration and your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
map $http_referer $ref {
    default $http_referer;
    ~*(badref.com) 1;
}
```

and to server section

```
if ($ref = '1') {
    set $ref "";
}
proxy_set_header Referer $ref;
```

For checking $request_uri and $http_referer in one condition you can use

```
map $http_referer$request_uri $ref {
    default $http_referer;
    ~*.*badref.com.*XXXXXXX.* "";
}
proxy_set_header Referer $ref;
```

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ I suggest to use the "" in the line " ~*(badref.com) 1;" instead of the if statement. for example `map $http_referer $ref {
  default $http_referer;
  ~*(badref.com) "";
}` you can then just use `proxy_set_header Referer $ref;`

Comment: Since my condition is related to $request_uri, how can I add this condition to "map" ?